# Hashing legacy salted passwords with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have an existing membership database where passwords are a hash of both username and a unique id.  As I understand, ASP.NET Identity will take care of salting passwords for you.

However, I need my old hashed passwords to work until they are updated (i.e. they need to work on the first login at which point I'll update it).

The `IPasswordHasher` has method: `VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)`.  This method doesn't allow me to pass in any sort of salt.  I realize I don't need to provide a value for any *new* hashed passwords, but for my existing ones I need to do a legacy check.

```
public class CoolGuyPasswordHasher : PasswordHasher {
    public IdentityContext DbContext { get; set; }

    // Custom hashing used before migrating to Identity
    public static string GetSHA1Hash(string password, string guid) {
        string passWithSalt = String.Concat(password, guid);
        return FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(passWithSalt, "SHA1");
    }

    // Verify if the password is hashed using SHA1. If yes, rehash using ASP.NET Identity Crypto which is more secure
    public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword) {
        //I can't pass in my salt!
        if (String.Equals(hashedPassword, GetSHA1Hash(providedPassword, wheresTheSalt), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            ReHashPassword(hashedPassword, providedPassword);
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
        }

        return base.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, providedPassword);
    }
}
```

In the code snippet above, notice in the call to `GetSHA1Hash` that I don't have a second parameter to pass in.

How could I go about doing my legacy salted password check?  In the new system I suppose I could make the hashed password stay as the result of the username + id.  However, since the implementation of ASP.NET Identity doesn't seem to cater towards that, what would be my best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the modern salts are stored is that they're just added to the hashed password value (see this: http://brockallen.com/2012/10/19/password-management-made-easy-in-asp-net-with-the-crypto-api/). So you might have to modify (*ahem* hack up) the UserManager to load the salt from the separate column and pass it into the password hasher as part of the hashed password.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Since I need to know when to concatenate (for old passwords) and when not to, is it at all safe to use the length of the existing hash as an indicator of whether it was previously hashed with SHA1?  According to documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.sha1(v=vs.111).aspx) the SHA1 hash will be 40 hexadecimal characters.  I understand that ASP.NET Identity uses `Crypto.HashPassword` under the hood (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.hashpassword(v=vs.111).aspx).  Can that hash be 40 characters?

Comment: Yea, sounds like a reasonable approach. Hash size is constant.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity) article; it has code samples extending the UserManager and using a crafted PasswordHasher which does exactly what you want.